# Крошка и крушить. Общая этимология?

Tags: этимология

Являются ли существительное **крошка** и глагол **крушить** этимологическими родственниками?

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая информация есть в "Этимологическом словарь русского языка" (М. Фасмер).

КРОХА
[кроха́](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6188.htm)
уменьш. **кро́шка**, др.-русск. **кръхъть** "крошка, крупинка", часто (см. Срезн. I, 1340), укр. криха́, блр. крыха́, цслав., др.-русск. кръха.
Родственно лит. krušà, kriušà (ж.), жем., вост.-лит. krùšas "град", вост.-лит. krū́šai (м. р. мн. ч.), krúšos (ж. р. мн. ч.), лтш. krusа "град", лит. krušù, krušaũ, krùšti "**дробить**, толочь", греч. κρούω "толку, стучу."

[круши́ть](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6208.htm)
укр. круши́ти, ст.-слав. съ-кроушити συντρίβειν, θραύειν, κρούειν, сербохорв. **кру́шити "крошить"**, словен. krúšiti, чеш. krušiti, польск. kruszyć, в.-луж. krušić. **От крух, кроха́**; см. Бернекер 1, 628 и сл.; Мейе, МSL 14, 363.

Обобщающие данные приводятся в "Этимологическом словаре Крылова".
[крушить](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/etymologic-dictionary/fc/slovar-202-2.htm)
Образовано от той же основы, что и **крухъ** – "осколок, обломок". Ту же основу, но с иной корневой гласной находим и в существительном **кроха**. Отметим родственное польское krachy – "хрупкий".

Да, существительное **крошка** и глагол **крушить** — это этимологически родственные слова.

Answer (score 1):

**Читать Фасмера — задача непростая.** (Здесь даже можно вспомнить Пастернака: Любить иных — тяжелый крест...).

**Вот у Черных всё понятно.** Да, ***крошка*** и ***крушить*** —  это родственники именно **этимологические,** хотя звуковой состав корня у них похожий. (В современном языке родственными являются  ***крошка*** и ***крошить***).

И.-е. корень ***krou-s/krus*** — толочь, разбивать, ломать.

В словах славянской и балтийской групп присутствуют **все эти значения,** а существительное может быть не только маленькой  *крохой/крошкой*, но и просто *осколком, обломком* и даже *градом.*

**Таким образом,** слова *крошка* и *крушить* имеют общий исторический корень, но при этом их **значения в современном языке различны.**

Значение  общего корня  связано **с делением на части**, но это значение в приведенных словах **дифференцируется:** ломать на части в глаголе *крушить* и делить на мелкие части в словах *крошить, крошка*.

Answer (score 0):

Крошка -> крошить 
Крушить, рушить <- разруха

> "оканчивать", pãbangas, pabangà "окончание", далее, др.-инд. bháŋgas "разруха, упадок, разорение, волна (Этимологический словарь Макса Фасмера)

Не являются.

> Разру́ха. Это существительное является, по всей видимости, заимствованием из польского языка, в котором существительное rozruch — «беспорядок», образованное от ruch — «движение». Произношение и написание разруха вместо розруха объясняется аканьем. (Происхождение слова разруха в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Крылова Г. А.)

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте свои ответы в соответствии с вопросом. В данном случае вопрос был о двух словах: крошка и крушить. Нужно ответить: а) являются ли они этимологическими родственниками (ударение вопросе может падать на два слова: явлЯются и этимологИческими); б) нужно  ясно изложить  свою точку зрения относительно именно этих слов, используя данные словарей.  У Вас же основная часть ответа посвящена анализу слова "разруха". Пожалуйста. отнеситесь к моему замечанию с пониманием. Нам очень интересно Ваше мнение, и мы приветствуем Ваше желание отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: Народная этимология (линг.) - переделка, непонятного (напр. заимствованного) слова, объясняемая потребностью сблизить его по звуковому подобию с каким-нибудь из привычных слов и таким образом осмыслить его, <br>
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1098334  <br> Либо понимание слов, либо смешение понятий?

Comment: Вы считаете, что здесь есть народная этимология? (Кстати, эта Ваша точка зрения  для меня ясной не была, отсюда и просьба к Вам - говорить подробнее и понятнее). Но Черных считает эти слова этимологически родственными, просто в действительности этот корень имеет не частное значение чего-то мелкого, а более общее значение.

Comment: Звуковое подобие не является подтверждением однородности, ведь однородность заключается в толковании. Пример: хлОпок и хлопОк.

Comment: Я уже писал, что есть слова по толкованию разные, но их принимают за тождественные слова, хотя оные говорят о разных понятиях: шлем и шелом; древо и дерево; глас и голос; брег и берег... в этих парах совершенно разные понятия, но они близкие.

Comment: Понятия разные, но исторический корень krou-s/krus один со значением "толочь, разбивать, ломать" (общая идея - делить на части?). Крушить - это разбивать, ломать; крошить, крошка - ближе к толочь.  Но есть еще глагол рушить (разруха), он к этому корню отношения не имеет. По Черных, у него собственный корень re /reu, передающий идею движения. сравнить (укр.)  рушати(ся) -  двинуться, тронуться.

Comment: Ага, в таком случае вам ещё пригодится "крушина" для объединения однородности "крушить" и "крошка". Крушить образовано от рушить -> разрушение, разруха.

Comment: Может быть, но Черных так не  думает, а я ему верю. Он в своих словарных статьях  проводит серьезный анализ слов. Вообще говоря, этимология - это особая наука, настоящих этимологов мало. А Вы как докажете, что крушить образовано от рушить? Самый простой вопрос: откуда формант К и что он означает?

Comment: Тогда он должен был затронуть момент где "крошить" имеет два значения: 1) Раздроблять на мелкие части, крошки.
"К. хлеб"
2) Сорить крошками чего-н. А вот этот пункт никак не вяжется с "крушить". Как вы объясните такое упущение?

Comment: Здесь Черных уже не нужен. Глагол крошить, как и любое слово, может развивать новые значения (по смежности).

Comment: Нужен, нужен Черных, потому что он умолчал эту сторону глагола. Ему нужно было сделать довод, он его сделал.